# Can we store image as string type of data in Coredata

Tags: iphone

in my iOS project i had a issue called storing an image in String format. I'm using Coredata. I'm inserting values into database using SQLite Database browser. Is there any way to store image in string format and retrieve it in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert NSData to string, You can try some encoding like [base64](https://github.com/yllan/FoundationAddition/).

Comment: i want to insert the data from sqlite database browser as a string, NSData means we insert the image programmatically.

Comment: NSLog your Base64 string. Copy the string and paste in the column value(in sqlite browser) to insert.

Comment: but i could not get the image after doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in `NSData` type attribute.

Comment: Actually i want to insert image from SQLite database browser, Using NSData means we insert it programmatically like i stored the image in some location and i browse the location and i want to store that location as a string. Is it possible from database browser.

Comment: Using NSData means that you insert binary data of an image. It's almost the same as opening image with text editor, copying everything you see there and inserting it into SQLite database through its browser.